# Viewing all the timeouts/intervals in javascript?

Tags: javascript, timeout, setinterval

I'm writing an application that utilizes JavaScript timeouts and intervals to update the page. Is there a way to see how many intervals are setup? I want to make sure that I'm not accidentally going to kill the browser by having hundreds of intervals setup.

Is this even an issue?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to enumerate active timers, but you could override `window.setTimeout` and `window.clearTimeout` and replace them with your own implementations which do some tracking and then call the originals.

```
window.originalSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.originalClearTimeout = window.clearTimeout;
window.activeTimers = 0;

window.setTimeout = function(func, delay) {
    window.activeTimers++;
    return window.originalSetTimeout(func, delay);
};

window.clearTimeout = function(timerID) {
    window.activeTimers--;
    window.originalClearTimeout(timerID);
};
```

Of course, you might not always call `clearTimeout`, but this would at least give you some way to track what is happening at runtime.

Comment: I used this in some code today, but I needed `activeTimers` to decrement when `clearTimeout` was *not* called.  That's easily accomplished by replacing the second line of `window.setTimeout` with this:  `return window.originalSetTimeout(function() {func(); activeTimers--;},delay);`

Comment: This answer will not be able to work any more since DOM-related JavaScript functions will be 'immutable'.

Answer (score 35):

I made a Chrome DevTools extension that shows all intervals. Cleared ones are greyed out.

[image: Timers Chrome Devtool extension]

**[setInterval-sniffer](https://github.com/NV/setInterval-sniffer)**

Comment: Sadly this appears to of stopped working with Chrome.

Comment: @JosephLennox This alternative works, tested just now: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/timeouts-and-intervals/oagmfffelnnohpbidjknmhfangoahcan?hl=en

Comment: @Trevor, that unfortunately doesn't seem to work anymore (with Chrome 97) either.

Comment: If anyone knows of a utility like this that still works, that would be great.

Comment: Please elaborate its workings...

Answer (score 14):

Instead of just have a count of timers, here is an implementation which stores all timerid's into an array. It only shows **active timers** while the accepted answer only counts calls to `setTimeout` & `clearTimeout`.

```
(function(w) {
    var oldST = w.setTimeout;
    var oldSI = w.setInterval;
    var oldCI = w.clearInterval;
    var timers = [];
    w.timers = timers;
    w.setTimeout = function(fn, delay) {
        var id = oldST(function() {
            fn && fn();
            removeTimer(id);
        }, delay);
        timers.push(id);
        return id;
    };
    w.setInterval = function(fn, delay) {
        var id = oldSI(fn, delay);
        timers.push(id);
        return id;
    };
    w.clearInterval = function(id) {
        oldCI(id);
        removeTimer(id);
    };
    w.clearTimeout = w.clearInterval;

    function removeTimer(id) {
        var index = timers.indexOf(id);
        if (index >= 0)
            timers.splice(index, 1);
    }
}(window));
```

This is how you can get the **count of active timers** on the page:

```
timers.length;
```

This is how you can **remove all active timers**:

```
for(var i = timers.length; i--;)
    clearInterval(timers[i]);
```

Known limitations:

- You can only pass a function (not a string) to `setTimeout` with this monkey patch.
- The function assumes `clearInterval` and `clearTimeout` do the same, which they do but it could change in the future.

Comment: Is it possible to get name of all running `SetIntervals`? For example `var timer = setInterval(function () { }` I need *timer* instead of count of running intervals.

Comment: Not that I know of, I'd suggest though a global search with the keyword "setInterval" and/or "setTimeout"

Answer (score 11):

Seeing as Paul has only covered setTimeout I thought I would share a counter for setInterval/clearInterval.

```
window.originalSetInterval = window.setInterval;
window.originalClearInterval = window.clearInterval;
window.activeIntervals = 0;
window.setInterval = function (func, delay)
{
    if(func && delay){
            window.activeIntervals++;
    }
    return window.originalSetInterval(func,delay);
};
window.clearInterval = function (intervalId)
{
    // JQuery sometimes hands in true which doesn't count
    if(intervalId !== true){
        window.activeIntervals--;
    }
    return window.originalClearInterval(intervalId);
};
```

Answer (score 5):

We've just [published](https://www.npmjs.com/package/time-events-manager) a package solving this exact issue.

```
npm install time-events-manager
```

With that, you can view and manage them via `timeoutCollection` object (and javascript's intervals via`intervalCollection` object).

`timeoutCollection.getScheduled();
timeoutCollection.getCompleted();
timeoutCollection.getAll();`

Comment: I think OP and most people were looking for something to either type in the browser's console as the first PoC and maybe later in an extension. How would one go about putting that in the console from the information you gave?

Answer (score 1):

I just needed something like this and this is what I've put together:

```
window.setInterval = function (window, setInterval) {
  if (!window.timers) {
    window.timers = {};
  }
  if (!window.timers.intervals) {
    window.timers.intervals = {};
  }
  if (!window.timers.intervals.active) {
    window.timers.intervals.active = {};
  }
  return function (func, interval) {
    var id = setInterval(func, interval);
    window.timers.intervals.active[id] = func;
    return id;
  }
}(window, window.setInterval);

window.clearInterval = function (window, clearInterval) {
  if (!window.timers) {
    window.timers = {};
  }
  if (!window.timers.intervals) {
    window.timers.intervals = {};
  }
  if (!window.timers.intervals.inactive) {
    window.timers.intervals.inactive = {};
  }
  return function (id) {
    if (window.timers.intervals.active && window.timers.intervals.active[id]) {
      window.timers.intervals.inactive[id] = window.timers.intervals.active[id];
      clearInterval(id);
      delete window.timers.intervals.active[id];
    }
  }
}(window, window.clearInterval);
```

This records the interval `id`s along with their functions, and also keeps track of their status (`active`/`inactive`).

Comment: Be careful using integers as object indexes. Its best to convert integers to strings before using as a key on an object in JavaScript. This way you don't collide with JavaScript's intrinsic index logic using integers. This used to be a problem way back in the day. Maybe its not any longer though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Alessio's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5268732/alessio-cantarella) answer. Below is my version. Has a bit more functionality for logging and inspection.

Here is some boilerplate that you can alter to utilize your own frameworks:

```
var s$ = function (s){return new String(s)}
var _w=window
_w.q$ = {
  getMachineTimeMS: function(){
      var d = new Date(), ms = d.getMilliseconds()
      var a = [d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds(), '-', ms<10?'00' + s$(ms):ms<100?'0'+s$(ms):ms]
      return a.join('')
  }
  ,getCaller: function(opts){
      return "(implement this)"
  }
}
```

Here is the main code:

```
_w.setTimeout = function (orig_setTimeout) {
  var t=(_w._Timers = _w._Timers||{})
  var d=(t.Timeouts = t.Timeouts||{})
  d.Active = d.Active||{}
  t.z_to_id_idx = t.z_to_id_idx||{}
  return function (h, n) {
    var t = _w._Timers, d = t.Timeouts
    var id = orig_setTimeout(h, n), ts = q$.getMachineTimeMS()
    var c = q$.getCaller({depth:2})
    t.z_to_id_idx[s$(id)] = d.Active[ts] = {sts: ts, id: id, h: h, n: n, scaller: c}
    return id;
  }
}(_w.setTimeout);

_w.clearTimeout = function (orig_clearTimeout) {
  var t=_w._Timers, d = t.Timeouts
  d.Inactive = d.Inactive||{}
  return function new_clearTimeout(id) {
    var t = _w._Timers, d = t.Timeouts, sId = s$(id)
    if (!d.Active || !sId in t.z_to_id_idx) return
    var r = t.z_to_id_idx[sId]
    r.ccaller = q$.getCaller({depth:2})
    r.cts = q$.getMachineTimeMS()
    d.Inactive[r.ts] = r;
    orig_clearTimeout(r.id);
    delete d.Active[r.ts]
    delete t.z_to_id_idx[sId]
  }
}(_w.clearTimeout);

_w.setInterval = function (orig_setInterval) {
  var t=(_w._Timers = _w._Timers||{})
  var d=(t.Intervals = t.Intervals||{})
  d.Active = d.Active||{}
  t.z_in_id_idx = t.z_in_id_idx||{}
  return function (h, n) {
    var t = _w._Timers, d = t.Intervals
    var id = orig_setInterval(h, n), ts = q$.getMachineTimeMS()
    var c = q$.getCaller({depth:2})
    t.z_in_id_idx[s$(id)] = d.Active[ts] = {sts: ts, id: id, h: h, n: n, scaller: c}
    return id;
  }
}(_w.setInterval);

_w.clearInterval = function (orig_clearInterval) {
  var t=_w._Timers, d = t.Intervals
  d.Inactive = d.Inactive||{}
  return function new_clearInterval(id) {
    var t = _w._Timers, d = t.Intervals, sId = s$(id)
    if (!d.Active || !sId in t.z_in_id_idx) return
    var r = t.z_in_id_idx[sId]
    r.ccaller = q$.getCaller({depth:2})
    r.cts = q$.getMachineTimeMS()
    d.Inactive[r.ts] = r;
    orig_clearInterval(r.id);
    delete d.Active[r.ts]
    delete t.z_in_id_idx[sId]
  }
}(_w.clearInterval);
```

Usage example:

```
id = setTimeout(()=>{console.log("CALLED")}, 10000)
clearTimeout(id)
setInterval(()=>{console.log("CALLED")}, 1000)

console.table(_w._Timers.Timeouts.Inactive)
```

The console.table will output a nicely formatted and inspectable table in the JavaScript Console

Answer (score 0):

Succeeding [@NVI's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16718225/15643772) I made extension to maintain timers easily.

You can find manual and code [here](https://github.com/PzaThief/chrome-timer-lookup).

[image: screenshoot]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35457230)