# Get named function to repeat itself continuously in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a function to repeat itself once it starts, but I must be off today because I can't figure it out. Here's my code:

```
function runNext() {
    galleryNext().delay(1500).runNext();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend using javascript's `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to call a function repeatedly

Comment: This will not work unless function runNext is a method of the object returned by delay.

Comment: `.delay()` is used for animations in the queue, I see no animations in your code, thus no queue exists to delay - stuff like `.slideUp()` for instance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to call a function on a regular interval you should use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval).

```
var myFunction = function() {};
setInterval(myFunction, 1000); // call every 1000 milliseconds
```

If you ever need to stop the function from being called forever, setInterval() returns an id that you can use to stop the timer as well. Here's an example.

```
var myFunction = function() {};
var timer = setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Comment: aha, stopping the function was going to be my next question. nice one.

Comment: The clearing of the interval should be done using `clearInterval(timer); `and not `clearTimeout(timer);` as timer is an interval. Although it is very likely this will work, if at any point the method to clearing an interval changes, the code above will not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913719/are-cleartimeout-and-clearinterval-the-same

Answer (score 2):

You can't attach a user defied function like a DOM method. jQuery chaining applies to DOM manipulation and animations, because each process returns the DOM node in question. Plus `delay` just delays an animation, what you want here is to run a function after some time constantly, so use setTimeout:

```
(function foo() {
  setTimeout(function() { foo() },1000);
  })();
```

Comment: This doesn't call the function continuously.

Comment: @jessegavin Yes...Yes it does.

Comment: I stand corrected. However, why not just use `setInterval()` ?

Comment: Yeah, you can use `setInterval`.

Comment: It depends on what the OP is trying to achieve. If he wants to start the delay after the processing is complete he would want to use setTimeout recursively. If he wants it to run every 1500ms, regardless of if the function has completed then he can use setInterval. If the delay is set shorter than the function takes to execute, it can freeze the browser.