# execute Jquery when the mouse stops moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have a quick script that has a trail follow the cursor:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
       $('.fall').each(function(){
           if ($(this).css("opacity") == 0){
               $(this).remove();
           };
       });
       t = (e.pageY - 10).toString() + 'px';
       l = (e.pageX - 10).toString() + 'px';
       $('.fall').css("margin_left",l);
       $('.fall').css("margin_top",t);
       var doit = '<div class="fall" style="position:fixed;margin-left:' + l + ';margin-top:' + t + ';">+</div>'
       $('body').prepend(doit);
      $('#status2').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);

       $('.fall').animate({
           marginTop: '+=50px',
           opacity: 0
       },1000);       
   }); 
});
```

Now I would like to remove the `animate` part and have something like the following when the mouse is not moving:

```
$('.fall').each(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    $(this).remove()
});
```

I just can't figure out how to execute this when the mouse is not moving for more than like a second. Any ideas?

Thanks, and [here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wVVbT/5/)

Comment: update a var `mouseLastMoved` each time it's moved and use a setTimeout to check that `now > mouseLastMoved + x seconds`?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want but I updated it to use your new code: http://jsfiddle.net/wVVbT/9/ - does this help?

Comment: I need that line to execute when the mouse stops moving...so the updated code you just posted is not what I want

Comment: @RyanSaxe - ok, what about this: http://jsfiddle.net/wVVbT/13/ (note: credit goes to adeneo, I just added and removed a few bits of code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

is this what you require? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wVVbT/15/)

```
lastTimeMouseMoved = new Date().getTime();
var t = setTimeout(function() {
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  if (currentTime - lastTimeMouseMoved > 1000) {
    $('.fall').fadeOut('slow');
    // $('.fall').remove();
  }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: That is almost perfect!! That is exactly the point...but it doesn't fade out, it just gets removed

Comment: just comment //  $('.fall').remove(); that will do

Comment: @Down voter - in case you downvote an answer please feel free to describe a reason for the same

Answer (score 15):

You add a timeout that fires after one second of inactivity, and clear the timeout if the mouse moves within 1 second etc :

```
var timer;
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
   clearTimeout(timer);

   timer = setTimeout(function() {
       $('.fall').fadeOut('slow', function() {
           $(this).remove();
       });
   }, 1000);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wVVbT/14/)

**EDIT:**

Here's how I'd do it

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wVVbT/18/)

Comment: The goal is to make them fade out when stopped. This doesn't do that, it just makes it stop drawing. and then you can't start again...

Comment: @RyanSaxe - But don't they already fade out? Anyway, edited the answer, same principle for figuring out when the mouse stopped for a second etc.

Comment: @adeneo - I think they want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wVVbT/13/ - all they need to do to make yours work how they want is to remove a few lines in their original function.

Comment: @adeneo +1 Great approach! Just a note. For best practices, your code above and in the fiddle should probably use clearTimeout, not clearInterval, since you're setting a timeout. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913719/are-cleartimeout-and-clearinterval-the-same