# jQuery event when user inactive or very active

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm looking for a jQuery script that will fire by inactive or very active visitors.

- when the user stops moving his mouse
- when the mouse goes out of browser
- if he has scrolled half the page
- when he scrolls up

Is that possible and is it ready?

Comment: Google Translate: 
I'm looking for a jQuery script that will wipe out inactive visitors.

When the user stops moving his mouse
When the mouse goes out of cattle
If he has scrolled half the page
when he scrolls up
Is that possible and is it ready?

Comment: eins fein polizei

Answer (score -1):

**when he scrolls up** - .scroll()

**when the user stops moving his mouse**- 
[execute Jquery when the mouse stops moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252532/execute-jquery-when-the-mouse-stops-moving)

**when the mouse goes out of browser** .mouseleave()  (you can set the event on the body).

**if he has scrolled half the page** -[Trigger JQuery function when passed half way down the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957658/trigger-jquery-function-when-passed-half-way-down-the-page)