# understanding an automatic page refresh in javascript

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout

I am trying to understand this code:

```
function setIdle(cb, seconds) {
    var timer; 
    var interval = seconds * 1000;
    function refresh() {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(cb, interval);
    };
    $(document).on('keypress, click', refresh);
    refresh();
}

setIdle(function() {
    location.href = location.href;
}, 5);
```

`setIdle` takes two arguments. Inside its function it has a function `refresh` that clears a timer on a `Timeout` function. Now every time when an event happens (`click`, `keypress`)  `refresh()` gets called.

and then finally this function gets called passing in another function and and int value (`5`) which later will be the amount of seconds for the timer. In that other function which later is represented through `cb` the page will be refreshed (`location.href = location.href;`).

This causes an automaticpage refresh every 5 seconds.

So now I don't understand if I put an additional function:

```
setIdle(function() {
        console.log('hi');
    }, 1);
```

Why is the second function only called once and not every second like the other one?

Comment: You might find a similar question interesting: [Detecting idle time in JavaScript elegantly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setIdle` doesn't run the callback function every 5 seconds. It runs it once, 5 seconds after you call `setIdle`, and if you type or click something the timeout gets pushed back again. So it runs it once, when you've been idle for 5 seconds.

The reason the page refreshes every 5 seconds is because the callback function reloads the page, and reloading the page runs all the Javascript in the page again, so that calls `setIdle()` again.

But your second use of `setIdle` doesn't reload the page, so it just logs `hi` once.

If you want to do something repeatedly every N seconds, use `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout`.

BTW, `clearInterval` should be `clearTimeout`. In most browser they're currently interchangeable, but there's no guarantee. See [Are clearTimeout and clearInterval the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913719/are-cleartimeout-and-clearinterval-the-same)