# How to clear timeout of self-restarting function on unmount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using a function that fetches a data from server to update a loading log table.

For this purpose I set a timeout for 15 second which is called inside the function. I need to clear this timeout on componentWillUnmount, because it modifies state and I don't need to mess with state of an unmounted component.

```
// LogTable is my component
const LogTable = () => {
  let timerId
  const getLoadingData = () => {
    //does something
    timerId = setTimeout(getLoadingData, 15000)
    //more code
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return function cleanup() {
      clearTimeout(timerId)
    };
  }, []);
}
```

The code above doesn't work, because `timerId` inside the `useEffect` function is undefined and I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: We need to know what the scope of that `let timerId` is.  Need to see some surrounding code - particularly where do you call `getLoadingData`?

Comment: try returning an arrow function `() => { clearInterval(timerId)}`

Comment: Sidenote: You call `clearInterval` with `timerId` returned by `setTimeout`

Comment: See [Are clearTimeout and clearInterval the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9913719/1563833)

Comment: I am sorry for `clearInterval`. In my actual code it was correctly written (`clearTimeout`), I just mistyped that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should actually write it as:

```
  const useTimeout = (task, time) => useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(task, time)
    return () => clearTimeout(id);  
 }, []);
```

That can then be used as:

```
   useTimeout(10000, () => {
     // ... do whatever
   })
```

Or in your specific usecase:

```
  const useInterval = (task, time) => useEffect(() => {
    let id;
    (async function job() {
       await task();
       id = setTimeout(job, time);
    })();
    return () => id && clearTimeout(id);  
 }, []); 

 useInterval(1000, async () => {
   //...
 });
```