# Clear all setIntervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm using `setIntervals` within an `each()` function like so

```
$(".elements").each(function() {
    setInterval(function() {

    }, 1000);
});
```

Obviously a setIntervals is created for each element.

My question is: How do I clear all the setIntervals when I no longer need them? I have tried storing the setInterval in a variable and call `window.clearInterval(int)`, but that only clears the last setInterval since each variable is overridden.

Comment: You could push each interval id into an array and then iterate over that when you want to clear them...

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635502/how-do-i-clear-all-intervals

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you set an interval, you get a pointer to it:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){}, 4000);
```

If you want to cancel an interval, you do the following:

```
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

So, for what you want to do, you would do the following:

```
var intervals = [];
$(".elements").each(function() {
    var i = setInterval(function() {

    }, 1000);
    intervals.push(i);
});
```

Then if you need to cancel them all you can do this:

```
intervals.forEach(clearInterval);
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: No. You would need to replace the for each with a for loop, or a lodash or jquery loop.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

There's no "clear-all-intervals" function.

You'll need to store all of them, and clear all of them:

```
var ints = [];

$(".elements").each(function() {
  ints.push( setInterval(function() {

             }, 1000) 
  );
});

// later

for ( var i = 0; i < ints.length; ++i )
  clearInterval( ints[i] );

ints = [];   // and forget them
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
// clear interval
var id = window.setInterval(function() {}, 0);
while (id--) {
window.clearInterval(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var clearAllIntervals = function ( ) {

    var intervals = [];

    $(".elements").each(function() {
        intervals.push( setInterval(function() {

        }, 1000) );
    });

    return function clearAll ( ) {
        intervals.forEach( clearInterval );
    }

}( );

// When you want to clear them:
clearAllIntervals( );
```

If you are wanting to be compatible with IE8 or under you should [shim .forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), or replace it with a library equivalent, or a plain loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since each interval is associated with an element, you could store the interval ID in the element:

```
$(".elements").each(function() {
  $(this).data('interval-id', setInterval(function() {
    // ...
  }, 1000));
});
```

Then, if you want to clear the intervals,

```
$(".elements").each(function() {
  clearInterval($(this).data('interval-id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you use this solution, but it really do the trick. The idea it to override setInterval function to collect all links to setInterval:

```
(function(originalSetInterval){
    var intervals = [];
    window.setInterval = function(func, timeout) {
        var newInterval = originalSetInterval(func, timeout);
        intervals.push(newInterval);
        return newInterval;
    }

    window.clearAllIntervals = function() {
        intervals.forEach(clearInterval);
    }
})(window.setInterval)
```

To do a better job you would also need to override clearInterval to remove all intervals being clear already:

```
(function(originalSetInterval, originalClearInterval){
    var intervals = [];
    window.setInterval = function(func, timeout) {
        var newInterval = originalSetInterval(func, timeout);
        intervals.push(newInterval);
        return newInterval;
    }

    window.clearInterval = function(interval) {
        originalClearInterval(interval);
        intervals.splice(intervals.indexOf(interval), 1)
    }

    window.clearAllIntervals = function() {
        intervals.forEach(clearInterval);
    }
})(window.setInterval, window.clearInterval)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set an interval, you get a pointer to it.
To clear all intervals, you'll need to store all of them:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(setInterval(function () {
    console.log(1);
  }, 1000));
arr.push(setInterval(function () {
    console.log(2);
  }, 1000));
arr.push(setInterval(function () {
    console.log(3);
  }, 1000));
```

Following loop will clear all intervals

```
// Clear multiple Intervals
  arr.map((a) => {
    console.log(a)
    clearInterval(a);
    arr = [];
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, an interval handle ID is an incremental whole number greater than 0. So, all you'd have to do is create a no-function interval, and then for-loop it to clear all intervals from your latest interval handle ID down to 1.

```javascript
let hInterval1 = window.setInterval(function(){console.log('interval A');},3000);
let hInterval2 = window.setInterval(function(){console.log('interval B');},3000);
for(let i = hInterval2; i > 0; i--) window.clearInterval(i);
```

If you run that sample, you'll see that we see 2 intervals running in the console emitting "interval A" and "interval B", and then by the time you run the for-loop, it stops both.