# Angular - How to call ngOnDestroy when change [src] in iFrame

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, memory-leaks, setinterval

I have one slide show application that support only many internal link.

HTML

```
<iframe width="100%" id="iframeSlide" height="100%" #iframe frameBorder="0" [src]="urlSafe"></iframe>
```

TS code

```
current.urlSafe = current.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(current.slideUrls[current.index]);
```

`slideUrls` is an array contains list of internal link, but when new url set to `current.urlSafe`, the old url did not call `ngOnDestroy` function to release resource.

I tried to set `current.urlSafe = "about:blank";`

or

```
var frame = document.getElementById("iframeSlide"),
frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
frameDoc.removeChild(frameDoc.documentElement);
```

But it did not call `ngOnDestroy` function.
In the internal page, I used setInterval function so need go to `ngOnDestroy` to clear the `Interval`, without it many request to called inside `setInterval`.

Links I refereed

https://web.dev/detached-window-memory-leaks/

[How do I clear all intervals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635502/how-do-i-clear-all-intervals)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the iframe src would be the equivalent to navigating to a new url in the browser address bar. The browser itself clears the top level JS/HTML resources in this case

`ngOnDestroy` would occur if you remove components or services within the app, but not on a refresh

Comment: but i use console log, the setInterval did not clear yet, how to clear interval in this case?

Comment: nope, all are internal link in angular app