# How would you terminate an infinite loop (`setInterval`) in the console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console

For instance, we could run

```js
setInterval(function(){console.log("Hello, SO!")}, 2000);
```

`Hello, SO!` gets repeated every two seconds in the terminal.  *There are 6 repeats in the picture below.*

[image]

Is there a key combination you could press or command you could type to stop the infinite loop in the console?

Comment: If you have no reference to the interval, your best bet would be to hit `F5` to refresh the page, or to clear every possible interval (since they are given numerical IDs by the browser): `for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++) clearInterval(i)`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6843415/1913729 . **Or** just use the ID you see in your console: `clearInterval(4491)`

Comment: @blex where are handles documented?  I checked mdn and it looks like the interval is a `int32`, but I couldn't find docs on the handle itself.

Comment: In the HTML Standard specification, they only refer to it as a _[user-agent-defined integer that is greater than zero](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps)_. In the specs implementation, they use a [`long`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#windoworworkerglobalscope)

Comment: @blex Thanks for that. So it could potentially be a very large number, but likely not since they're incremented.

Answer (score 2):

This is your best bet that I know of.

```
var interval = setInterval(() => console.log("hello, world"), 2000);
clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 2):

To kill intervals, you need a handle to them to pass to `clearInterval()`.  In your image, after you execute `setInterval()`, you can see the handle is returned to the console as `4491`.  In this way, you can kill it like so:

```
clearInterval(4491);
```

Alternatively (and better), you should assign that handle return to a variable so you can kill it programmatically:

```
let interval = setInterval(() => console.log('Hello, SO!'), 2000);
clearInterval(interval);
```

---

Edit:
You can also brute-force.  The handle is an `int64` number, so it could potentially be enormous, but for almost any app, it'll be small since the handles are incremented.  Note that this method could break other packages that rely on intervals.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 9999; i++) clearInterval(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop script execution on the current page using the pause button described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Step_through_code). This will pause all JS on the page though, not just your interval.