# stop Javascript function with another Javascript call?

Tags: javascript, function, popupwindow

In the original Javascript is there I want this to stop it

```
setTimeout('open_popup()',  200);
```

What is function To stop this from another file js

Comment: Do you mean you want to stop the setTimeout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141064/how-to-stop-all-timeouts-and-intervals-using-javascript is helpful

Comment: When you put a string in `setTimeout`, it will be `eval`ed. `setTimeout` expects a function as a first parameter, so you'll be fine just using `setTimeout(open_popup, 200)`.

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` returns a handle that you can use the clear the timeout:

```
var timer = setTimeout(open_popup,  200);

clearTimeout(timer);
```

That of course assumes you put the `timer` variable in a scope that is accessible to both scripts and that you clear the timeout before it fires.

Comment: Also note that he passed the actual function to `setTimeout()`, and not a string to be `eval()`d. Using `eval()` (or any other function that internally `eval()`s code) is usually considered a bad practice. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: not work this code plz see this code i wont to stop <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.poparb.com/grbb/code.js"></script>