# How do I modify/overwrite a javascript function that is called by an infinite setInterval?

Tags: javascript, xss, intervals

Lets say we have this code that I don't have access to/ I cannot change.

```
function f() {
// bad tasks
}
setInterval(f, 10000);
```

I want to modify function f so I write something like this underneath.

```
window.f = function(){
// good tasks
}
```

But the original function `f()` with `bad tasks` in it are still running every 10 seconds. Seems like the function passed into `setInterval` is still pointing to the original function.
How do I stop it?

Comment: You sure what _function with bad code_ is defined as: `function f(){}` but not `var f=function(){}`?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct: the interval keeps a reference to the original `f`.

There is no way to change this without editing the original script. All you can do is clear all intervals on the site and start another interval. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8860203/27862 for that.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
function f() {
    //bad tasks
}

setInterval(function() { f(); }, 10000);

window.f = function() {
    //good tasks
}
```

so that timer will call not the old f() passed to it but rather a function named f at the moment.

Other way:

```
function f() {
    //bad tasks
}

var interval = setInterval(f, 10000);

function g() {
    //good tasks
}

clearInterval(interval);
setInterval(g, 10000);
```

Comment: Seeing the question, I don't think Noob is able to change the `setInterval` part.

Comment: Your first way do not work (tested). Second way cannot work for Noob because _code that I don't have access to/ I cannot change_ and Noob cannot clear old interval.

Comment: @AndrewD. If Noob is willing to clear all current intervals, he could kill the interval in question (just loop from 0 to the next interval-id from `setInterval` and clear every interval ;))

Comment: @AndrewD. could you please say how did you tested it? It works on my configuration: https://gist.github.com/2411806 . It won't help Noob, as Yoshi explained, but it should work nevertheless.

Comment: @penartur, I want say that `setInterval (function () {f ();}, 10000),` does not replace the original `setInterval(f, 10000); ' and cannot help.

Comment: @AndrewD. I meant modifying the existing code (so that instead of `f` itself the closure on `f` will be passed to `setInterval`, which will allow changing `f` in the outer scope).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `setInterval`, use `setTimeout` instead. It will give you the control you need.

```
function f() {
 // bad tasks
 fTimeout = setTimeout(f,1000);
}
//start
var fTimeout = setTimeout(f,1000);
```

now if something bad is going on and you want to rewrite `f`:

```
clearTimeout(fTimeout);
window.f = function() { 
            /* good stuff */ 
            fTimeout = setTimeout(f,1000);
           }
fTimeout = setTimeout(f,1000);
```

[See also](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/05/14/setinterval-is-moderately-evil.aspx)