# Prevent JavaScript function from running twice (setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout, execution

I have this function that runs for several seconds with the use of `setTimeout`. This function is ran when a button is clicked.

```
function complete() {
    var div = document.getElementById('log');
    setTimeout(function(){ div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + intro[Math.floor(Math.random() * intro.length)] + "<br>"; }, 500);
    setTimeout(function(){ div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + second[Math.floor(Math.random() * second.length)] + "<br>"; }, 2560);
    setTimeout(function(){ div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + third[Math.floor(Math.random() * third.length)] + "<br>"; }, 4860);
    setTimeout(function(){ div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + fourth[Math.floor(Math.random() * fourth.length)] + "<br>"; }, 7860);
    setTimeout(function(){ div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + fifth[Math.floor(Math.random() * fifth.length)] + "<br>"; }, 9640);
}
```

However, if the user clicks the button multiple times, this function begins to excute multiple times as well. I have tried to prevent this from occuring by using the code below, however, it is not working.

```
var running;
function complete() {
    if (running == true) { alert('error'); }
    running = true;
    var div = document.getElementById('log');
    setTimeout(function(){ div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + intro[Math.floor(Math.random() * intro.length)] + "<br>"; }, 500);
    setTimeout(function(){ div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + second[Math.floor(Math.random() * second.length)] + "<br>"; }, 2560);
    setTimeout(function(){ div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + third[Math.floor(Math.random() * third.length)] + "<br>"; }, 4860);
    setTimeout(function(){ div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + fourth[Math.floor(Math.random() * fourth.length)] + "<br>"; }, 7860);
    setTimeout(function(){ div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + fifth[Math.floor(Math.random() * fifth.length)] + "<br>"; }, 9640);
    running = false;
}
```

What approach should I take, or how can I fix my code so it can accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Store the timeouts and clear them on subsequent clicks.

Comment: I believe you'd want to set `running = false;` at the end of the execution _inside_ your timeouts. You could use a timeout, to run all other timeouts, and at the end of those timeoutes run `running = false;` may do the trick. So 'false' only gets set once in each loop AFTER all the elements run. You can then run `clearTimeout()` to stop the loops.

Comment: You could use `clearTimeout` to stop them when you first execute `complete()`. If you want to clear them all at once, [refer to this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860188/is-there-a-way-to-clear-all-time-outs) for an example.

Comment: A simple solution would be to remove the event listener from the `button`. How to do it, depends on how have you attached the listener. Can you show, how the listener is attached?

Comment: .. you should also `return` after the alert otherwise the rest of the function will still be executed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `running = false;` should be inside timeout function, as timeout will execute asyncronically, the `running = false;` will execute before your timeout ends

A simple example would be

```
var running = false,
    div = document.getElementById('response'),
    limit = 5,
    current = 0;

$('#trigger').click(function () {
    if (running === true) {
        alert('Error: The cycle was running. Aborting.');
        running = false;
        return false;
    }
    running = true;
    var end = setInterval(function () {
        if (current >= limit || running == false) {
            running = false;
            clearInterval(end);
        }
        div.innerHTML += 'Hello World<br />';
        current++;
    }, 500);

});
```

## [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/QDLkR/)

Comment: I just explained that to him in my comment on his post. Upvoted ;)

Comment: Yeah, saw after I posted answer. I can edit to include your extended explanation if you want

Comment: Thank you! However, how can I stop the rest of the function from running after the alert as well?

Comment: You can use a `return false;` after the alert so it exits the function

Comment: you can add a if statement in the timeouts to clear them if running was changed to false `if( running == false ) clearTimeout();`

Comment: I added an example to this answer. I used jQuery just to simplify a click for this example. Rest is JS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've used `addEventListener` to attach the click event to the button, you could remove the listener while timeouts are in progress:

```
function complete() {
    var div = document.getElementById('log'),
        button = this;
    this.removeEventListener('click', complete);
    setTimeout(function(){...});
                 :
    setTimeout(function(){...});
    // If you later want to make the button clickable again, just uncomment the line below:
    // setTimeout(function () {button.addEventListener('click', complete);}, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for stop running timer you have to clear him

```
        var stopTimer;

        function someFunction() {
            stopTimer= setTimeout(function(){
                console.log("something done");
            }, 3000);
        }

        function stopFunction() {
            clearTimeout(stopTimer);
        }
```