# Jquery: Short code for multiple clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, multiple-instances, cleartimeout

I have to clear multiple setTimeout functions

```
$('#stop').click(function(){
    clearTimeout(anim1);
    clearTimeout(anim2);
    clearTimeout(anim3);
    clearTimeout(anim4);
    clearTimeout(anim5);
    clearTimeout(anim6);
    clearTimeout(anim7);
    clearTimeout(anim8);
    clearTimeout(anim9);
    clearTimeout(anim10);
});
```

Is there any way to short this code something like `clearTimeout(anim1,anim2,anim3...);` I have already tried this with coma separation but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860188/is-there-a-way-to-clear-all-time-outs

Comment: The 'accepted answer' on that duplicate makes me cringe.

Comment: @user2864740 yeah, the answer after that is the one the poster should be using

Comment: Thanks guys, the 2nd answer in duplicate question helped me, as well as zedd's code and reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put them in an array and iterate over them

```
var timers = [anim1, anim2, anim3, anim4] //can also be added when created
for (var t=0;t<timers.length;t++) {
   clearTimeout(timers[t]);
}
```

In general when you need to perform the same operation on many or an unknown amount of objects you should put them in an array or structure them in an object where you can adress "all" items programmaticly. Heres a comphrehensive guide to [indexed collections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections)