# How do I halt periodic DOM refreshes on a page?

Tags: javascript, debugging, dom, google-chrome-devtools, setinterval

I'm on a page that probably has a interval timer which refreshes a table every several seconds -- now I want to stop this timer (not sure how to "sniff out" this timer or grab a hold of it) or somehow cancel or prevent these automatic periodic DOM refreshes -- so that I can play with styling in the debugging tool? By the way, jQuery is available.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860188/is-there-a-way-to-clear-all-time-outs

Answer (score 0):

this `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />` that makes the web will refresh, you can use that to will refresh each many hours

Answer (score 0):

Placing a break on 'subtree modification' in DevTools seems to work.