# Ionic&AngularJS, timeout not canceled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, timer, timeout

I'm stuck because of timer issue.

Briefly, the code submits a form and the answer to the post is opened in an iFrame. 
An EventListener on the form allows me to detect the "submit" and apply a timer to detect if the iFrame loading is too long.
But, even if the iFrame is loaded (=timer should be canceled), the timer's function is called.
Here is the code :

```
[...]
var el = document.getElementById("myForm");
if(el){
el.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    $scope.popupOpened=false;

    var iframeWindow = window.parent.document.getElementById('myIframe');
    var iframeDoc = iframeWindow.contentWindow.document;

    //7 seconds before the popup is shown up
    $rootScope.myTimer = $timeout(function(){
        window.frames[0].stop();
        if(!$scope.popupOpened){
        errorConnexion2();//popup opening
        }
    }, 7000);

    iframeWindow.onload=function(){
    console.log("iframe loaded");
        //cancel the timer
        $timeout.cancel($rootScope.myTimer);
   }
 });
}
```

[...]

I also tried with setTimeout and clearTimeout and by clearing all of them like that :[Is there a way to clear all time outs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860188/is-there-a-way-to-clear-all-time-outs)

What am I missing ?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the reason why the timer wasn't canceled !

I tryied to debug, set alert() when the form was submitted and it figured out that the programm was entering multiple times in the submit eventListener.
I though about catching all timers IDs and killing them but I finally decided to give up and find the root cause.

The issue was on my view, in the .html page I was calling multiple times 'ng-controller="MyCtrl"' ! So, I just deleted the extra ones and the program worked !

Hope it helps !