# determine content of setinterval callback

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I've encountered a very badly designed website, and most of the "dynamic" content on the site is changed within `setTimeout`/`setInterval` functions.

There is one very annoying `setInterval` function which checks page activity very quickly, and I would like to override this function.

What I tried is clearing all the `setInterval` values, one by one to check if the function stopped. Also, clearing all the possible `setInterval` values like this: `for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) clearInterval(i);`, stops the "dynamic" page rendering, **WHICH I DONT WANT TO**

Question: 1. is there any way to look into the `interval` or `timeout` function and clear them?
2. is there a better way?

My current solution: I'm overriding the `setInterval` and `setTimeout` before page loaded, and log the function `.toString()` within.

Comment: Yes. You can use <a href="https://reactjs.org/">ReactJS</a> for better website.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have access to the website's code itself and are writing a user-script/extension to modify it. Is that correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript: Clear all timeouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860188/javascript-clear-all-timeouts)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, you cannot determine anything about the `setTimeout`/`setInterval` callback given a timerId. It sounds as if you don't have access to edit the underlying Javascript to prevent this action. If you can get your JS to load before the code in the page, then what you can do is replace `setInterval` or `setTimeout` with your own code, where you can increase the interval to whatever you want. For example:

```
let setTimeoutOld = setTimeout;
setTimeout = (cb, interval) => {
    if (interval < 1000) {
        interval = 1000;
    }
    setTimeoutOld(cb, interval);
}
```

Now if the page does something like:

```
setTimeout(() => { console.log('fired') }, 1);
```

The timeout won't fire until at least 1000ms have passed. If you only wanted to modify a specific `setTimeout` based on the contents of the cb, you could do what you mentioned in your work-around: calling `.toString()` on the function and comparing it to some previously generated `.toString()` (partial or complete) and then doing whatever you wanted.

Comment: If they can execute scripts before the page, then they could also try to log the signature of the guilty function (either its name if unique enough, either its toString). Once found, they might be able to change the timeout of only this function.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have access to code wherever it's setting timeout or interval.
So just take a global array and push it's output to it. Then iterate that array to clear everything.

#### For ex.

```
timeouts = [];
```

now, in code where there's timeout like

```
var timeout = setTimeout(<callback> , <interval> ); // push it's output to that global.
timeouts.push(timeout);
```

Then at the very end clear that.

```
   for(time of timeouts) {
     clearTimeout(time); 
   }
```

Similarly, for Interval.

Hope this is what you are looking for.