# How to stopp every running javascript function (also inline)

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to create a script which can stop every Javascript function. 
e.g

```
<button onclick='doSomething()'></button>
```

or

```
setInterval(doSomething, 200);
```

Is it possible to stop and disable those functions with another Javascript-File
I mean get every interval like getElementByTanName(interval) and the a for function to clear them all

Comment: put the interval in a variable, and then clear it using `clearTimeout`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setInterval and how to use clearInterval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/setinterval-and-how-to-use-clearinterval)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop all timeouts and intervals using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141064/how-to-stop-all-timeouts-and-intervals-using-javascript)

Comment: @evolutionxbox do you know how to clear every interval without knowing the var name of them like getElementByTagName(intervals)

Comment: There seem to be 3 possible questions here: 1) [how to remove all event handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386300/javascript-dom-how-to-remove-all-events-of-a-dom-object) attached to the DOM; 2) how to stop all timeouts and intervals -- see previous comments; and 3) can you stop functions that have already been triggered by a timer or event handler? I think the answer to 3 is no.

Comment: These answers cover stopping all JS execution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550574/how-to-terminate-the-script-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298839/is-it-possible-to-stop-javascript-execution

Answer (score 0):

You need assing interval to variable, then you will be able to stop it using [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/clearInterval) function.

```
var interval = setInterval(function, 5000)
if(finished){
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```