# List of functions to be called by window.setTimeout or window.setInterval in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript - Is it possible to view all currently scheduled timeouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817526/javascript-is-it-possible-to-view-all-currently-scheduled-timeouts)

Is there any way to access the list of all functions that are scheduled to be called (or strings scheduled to be evaluated) by `window.setTimeout()` or `window.setInterval()`?

Something that returns an Array of objects identical to those returned when these functions were originally called.

Comment: Can you be more specific. Not able to understand your question. From my understanding, you can always look at the API to find the arguments. etc.

Comment: I was trying to understand how a JS module (that I did not write) works. Just wanted to examine how it behaves.

Answer (score 1):

No. The [`WindowTimers`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html) interface doesn't provide any method to get the list of currently queued tasks:

```
[Supplemental, NoInterfaceObject]
interface WindowTimers {
  long setTimeout(in any handler, in optional any timeout, in any... args);
  void clearTimeout(in long handle);
  long setInterval(in any handler, in optional any timeout, in any... args);
  void clearInterval(in long handle);
};
Window implements WindowTimers;
```

You have to write your own code in order to keep track of the handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can except you write a wrapper for setTimeout and setInterval and implement calling them inside and pushing the functions to an Array

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question (although I don't think there is a way), but depending on what you're trying to do, you could write a wrapping function and then either add it to an array that you control or fire an event you can put a listener on, or ...

Of course, this would only give you control over what functions you set a timer on yourself.

```
var stack = new Array();

window.mySetTimeout = function (func, delay) {
   stack.push(func);
   window.setTimeout(func, delay); 
}

function doSomething () {
   return true;
}

window.mySetTimeout(doSomething, 500);
console.log(stack);
```

Edit: I guess I was a little slow there.