# Is there a way to find out how many intervals are active in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, html, setinterval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Viewing all the timouts/intervals in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858619/viewing-all-the-timouts-intervals-in-javascript)

I'm making an HTML5 game, and recently I've added a lot of graphical effects that rely on intervals (made by the `setInterval` function). It started running slow, even when no intervals should be running! So, I believe that I'm not clearing them all, and I'd like to do that. But how? First of all, of course, is to figure out if that's even the problem, so how do I get the number of currently active intervals?

Damn, the interval count never goes up more than 3, I **was** careful after all. I think I just set the terminal velocity too low!

Comment: *"...how do I get the number of currently active intervals?"* Keep track of them.

Comment: Wrap the `setInterval`, `clearInterval` and their `Timeout` brethren in your own versions that do bookkeeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap all Interval functions. For example:

```
myInterval = function(func, sec) {
   myInterval.count = myInterval.count + 1 || 1;
   setInterval(func, sec); 
};
myInterval("console.log(1)", 3000);
myInterval("console.log(2)", 3000);
```

Then

```
console.log(myInterval.count); // => 2
```

The same for clearInterval, and Timeout functions