# Show all currently running setIntervals

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway to see all ongoing `setIntervals`

If I make intervals global

```
b = setInterval(function(){
  $("body").append("B <br>");
},500);
```

I can see them when I, but I can't really see that they are intervals.

```
console.dir(Object.keys( window ));

Array[15]
    0: "top"
    1: "window"
    2: "location"
    3: "external"
    4: "chrome"
    5: "v8Intl"
    6: "v8Locale"
    7: "document"
    8: "jQuery171033813792187720537"
    9: "resizeJSBin"
    10: "$"
    11: "jQuery"
    12: "a"                            <--this is an interval!
    13: "local"
    14: "b"                            <--this is an interval!
    length: 15
        __proto__: Array[0]
```

Is there anyway to get information about all the intervals being run at a particular time. Like, see at what interval they are running, what code is being executed at that interval?

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/omupax/1/edit)

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this.  You can make a wrapper that will call `setInterval`/`clearInterval` for you, so you can keep track of them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858619/viewing-all-the-timouts-intervals-in-javascript

Comment: @MohammadAdil It's a duplicate then. Vote to close

Comment: @RocketHazmat would there be a way to do this from the console on a third-party site so you could see what exactly the page is running on your computer? Thanks!

Comment: @Ian Does the fact that I'd like to be able to do this from the browser console set it aside as sufficiently different?

Comment: @thomas I believe you're coming too late if you're coming with the console

Comment: @thomas: If you could "install" your wrapper before any of the code was ran, then probably.  However, you can probably use your browsers other debugging tools to see what's going on.

Comment: @thomas it's only so different that the answer would be; "no, you have to intercept the page load"

Comment: @RocketHazmat Okay, cool. Can you give me an example of how to do that?

Comment: A user-script might be able to instrument SI in time, then you could query the interceptor from the console

Comment: @thomas: Sorry, but I can't.  I'm just good at throwing out ideas ;-)  Not sure if any of them will really work.

Comment: @JanDvorak Do you know of any scripts that would be able to do this?

Comment: @thomas I suggest writing one. I'm not aware of any such script existing, but there could be. Such a script is not difficult to write.

Comment: `setInterval = (function(oldSI){return function(){...}}(setInterval)`

Comment: most of the work would be to convince the userscript manager to run your script _before_ the page load.