# GhostDriver / PhantomJS - How to block pop-ups?

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I need to disable a pop-up on a site, because it's causing `PhantomJSDriver` to crash.

The options are:

1. Block any pop-up from opening
2. Disable JavaScript entirely, so the pop-up won't load (which seems not to be possible as mentioned [here](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/253))
3. Override that specific JavaScript function which loads the pop-up.

So... How to block pop-ups in `PhantomJSDriver`?

Answer (score 1):

Overwriting the function setInterval and setTimeout could be a way to achieve this.
I would expect a popup to be a pretty long timeout, like many seconds so you could redirect it to the read timeout function if shorter, or cancel it if longer.

[Viewing all the timouts/intervals in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858619/viewing-all-the-timouts-intervals-in-javascript)