# How to stop a script completely when its tag is removed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've a script from a page tracker website, which do something periodically. Sometimes I need to re-run the script from scratch. To make this happen, I remove the script tag from DOM and append it again.

Since, the script uses `setInterval` the execution won't be finished when the `script` tag is removed.

What do you suggest for that?

Comment: You can override `setInterval`/`setTimeout` implementations *before* that script loads. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858619/viewing-all-the-timeouts-intervals-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

How about calling `clearInterval` ? 
You'll need the handle to the interval, though.

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

But if you can't or don't want to edit a 3rd party script, there is one thing you could do:

- override the window.setInterval function.

like

```
var backup = window.setInterval;
var my_array = [];


window.setInterval = function(interval, function){
    var handle = backup(interval, function);
   my_array.push(handle);
   return handle;
}
```

then you can get all the handles from my_array, and clear them all. 
Naturally, this would have to be done **before** you load any other scripts.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the case. The interval has been set somewhere inside the loaded script. Maybe there are more that one `setInterval`s, and I don't have their handlers. Is there anyway to stop all those `intervals` by removing the `script` tag?

Comment: @Afshin: Nope, you need to clear the interval, removing the script-tag doesn't suffice. You could reload the page, but that's an ugly hack:  window.location.reload(); But you could override the setInterval-function - see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use the clearInterval() method, you must use a variable when creating the interval method:

```
myTimer = setInterval("javascript function", milliseconds);
```

Then you will be able to stop the execution by calling the clearInterval() method.

```
clearInterval(myTimer );
```

Using module pattern you can Wrap your code in an IFFE to be able to use it without removing it from dom and reinitialize it with attaching it again.

```
const snifferModule= (function() {
  let globVariable= null;
  let globalArray= [];
  var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

 const initialize = function(gv, ga) {
    globVariable= gv;
    globalArray= ga;
  };

 const cleanAndRun= function() {
   clearInterval(myVar);
   // rest of code
  };

return {
    initialize,
    cleanAndRun,

  };
})();
```